# Set current date as maxDate in Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I'm developing an `Android` application using `Appcelerator Titanium`.

In that application I need to show a date picker when a particular text field is selected. The maximum value of date should be limited to current date and minimum value should be limited to `1990 Jan 1`.

#### What I have tried so far

#### 1

```
dateEntry.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
    var date = dateEntry.value;
    var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
        type:Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_DATE,
        minDate:new Date(1990,01,01),
        maxDate:new Date(),
        value:new Date(),
    });
    picker.showDatePickerDialog({
        value: new Date(),
        callback: function(e) {
            if (e.cancel)
            {
                dateEntry.value = date;
            }
            else
            {
                date = e.value;
                dateEntry.value = date;
            }
            dateEntry.blur();
        }
    });
});
```

But it is not working.

#### 2

I set `maxDate` and `minDate` for the `pickerDialog` also but it also not working.

#### 3

I hard-coded the current date as maxDate, it is also not working.

How can I achieve this ? Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Midhun, This is a bug with Titanium. You can see the comment by Ygor Lemos at [Jira](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-2978).

> It won't work if you use the Date Picker together with the
>   showDatePickerDialog() method. It just ignores the min/max dates
>   parameters.

Another option you have is validate the date selected with the current date.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

`var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
     type : Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_DATE,
     minDate : new Date(1990,00,01), //1990 Jan 1
     maxDate : new Date(), // Current Date
     value : new Date(),
 });`